# How to avoid ssh passphrase while using git on bluehost

Tags: git, redmine, bluehost

I'm using assembla as git repository. I want to keep a local version to my bluehost hosting. each time i ask to fetch the latest copy, it ask me to put passphrase -

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa':
```

How can i avoid this? One more thing, if i add a command on cron for git as below

```
cd /path/to/project.git && git fetch -q
```

it tells

```
/bin/sh: git: command not found
```

How to solve this too?

BTW, i'm trying to figure this for my [redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) tool.
Thanks
Musa
Musa

Comment: If you have two questions, please post two questions instead of grouping them into one.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a SSH-agent that will store the deciphered key in memory.

This is really easy under unix, just launch `eval $(ssh-agent)` and then `ssh-add` this will ask you for your password and then store the key.

For the cron problem, try entering the full path, you can obtain it with `which git` on any shell.

Comment: Thanks, i tried ssh-agent and then ssh-add command to my hosting, it says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." what's the wrong? Also i will add git fetch command on my cron to fetch from remote host, does that work with cron task?

Comment: try launching "`eval $(ssh-agent)`" it should work, I'll update my answer. `git fetch` in a cron task should work, but I don't know what will happen if there's a merge conflict

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [keychain](http://agriffis.n01se.net/keychain/) which takes care of starting ssh-agents as needed. From the rpm package description:

> Keychain is a manager for OpenSSH,
>   ssh.com, Sun SSH and GnuPG agents. It
>   acts as a front-end to the agents,
>   allowing you to easily have one
>   long-running agent process per system,
>   rather than per login session. This
>   dramatically reduces the number of
>   times you need to enter your
>   passphrase from once per new login
>   session to once every time your local
>   machine is rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your public key to ~/.ssh/authorized_keys on BlueHost. 
See http://ionrails.com/2009/08/29/bluehost-login-to-your-ssh-account-without-typing-in-a-password/ for more info. I also remember finding this in the user forums for BlueHost

I can not verify this firsthand since I have just been cut and pasting the passphrase when I do a git pull.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a link which tells you exactly how to do this:

http://linuxconfig.org/passwordless-ssh

Take note of the first comment. I needed to substitute the scp command just as that commenter suggested.

Comment: I don't know if hostingrails.com changed.  If not, this is a sad clickbait and should be removed.